# Is it possible to use a namespace in PHP from a variable?

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to use a [namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in PHP from a variable. I want to load classes dynamically based on a configuration array; something like that:

```
foreach ($content_types as $key => $content_type) {
  $namespace = $content_type['entity'];
  use $namespace;
}
```

Instead doing this:

```
use Bundle\Entity\User;
use Bundle\Entity\Project;
```

Note: I am using Symfony, the error message returned when I do that is:

> Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure if I get you right, but you want probably just this

```
foreach ($content_types as $key => $content_type) {
    $class = $content_type['entity'];
    $entity = new $class();
    // do something with $entity..
}
```

Comment: OP doesnt want instantiate, but requiring them

Comment: You don't have to "require" them, if you dont use them, and if you already know the fqcn, you could just work with them

Comment: Yeah it worked! Apparently I was mixing namespace and class concepts. I didn't know I could just initiate a new object this way. Thank you